# SQL REPLICATE - weird results

Tags: sql

Perhaps I've been at this for a few too many hours, but there is something very odd about the results of this statement.

The result of this statement

> (1) datalength(rtrim([last name])) as
>   last_name_length

is 10.

The result of the next statement, which I want to use for padding the last_name column with spaces,

> (2) datalength(REPLICATE(' ', (30 -
>   datalength(rtrim([last name])))))

is 20.

You would think that the result of this statement,

> (3) datalength(rtrim([last name]) +
>   REPLICATE(' ', 30 -
>   datalength(rtrim([last name]))))

would be 30.

It isn't. It's 50. The result of statement (3) is consistently greater than that of statement (2) by 30. It's as if I'm using a + operator in the REPLICATE statement instead of a -.

I've Googled this again and again and I don't see what's wrong with the syntax. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the datatype of `[last name]`?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) instead of [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) for the following reasons:

- DATALENGTH counts trailing spaces where LEN does not.
- DATALENGTH reports length in bytes, so for unicode strings (e.g., nchar, nvarchar) the number reported looks like it's doubled compared to the value returned by LEN.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you want is to pad it to 30 chars, just use STR

```
select STR([last name], 30)
```

#### Original answer below

---

I can replicate your issue

```
declare @last_name nvarchar(30)
set @last_name = '12345'
select
    datalength(rtrim(@last_name)) as last_name_length,
    datalength(REPLICATE(' ', (30 - datalength(rtrim(@last_name))))),
    datalength(rtrim(@last_name) + REPLICATE(' ', 30 - datalength(rtrim(@last_name))))
```

Output

```
last_name_length             
---------------- ----------- -----------
10               20          50
```

To fix it, simply using LEN doesn't work, it results in (because trailing spaces are not counted)

```
last_name_length             
---------------- ----------- -----------
5                0           5
```

Instead, divide all datalength results by 2

```
declare @last_name nvarchar(30)
set @last_name = '12345'
select
    datalength(rtrim(@last_name))/2 as last_name_length,
    datalength(REPLICATE(' ', 30 - datalength(rtrim(@last_name))))/2,
    datalength(rtrim(@last_name) + REPLICATE(' ', 30 - datalength(rtrim(@last_name))/2))/2
```

Comment: wow, glad I wasn't going completely around the bend. Thanks to all who responded and I'll give the divide by 2 item a try.

Comment: @qa_test If I guess correctly, simply using STR will do the job better